# Expressão regular para datas sem separador

Tags: regex

Tenho que saber se uma sequência de 8 números é uma data valida no formato dd/mm/aaaa.
O mais próximo que cheguei foi usando esta expressão:

```
/^[0-3]{1}\d{1}[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}[1-2]{1}\d{3}$/gm;
```

Mas ela esta retornando verdadeiro para sequências que não são datas validas como por exemplo:

```
39091991 (39/09/1991)
10181991 (10/18/1991)
```

Também gostaria que o ano tivesse um limite, `1990 - 2020`.

Não sou muito com com expressões regulares, então se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: O problema está sendo que expressões regulares não entendem que valores só podem ir de X a Y, como no caso dos dias, que variam com o mês (piora ainda mais o problema!) e com o ano (para fevereiro). O que pode ser feito seria validar a data após capturá-la.

Comment: De fato, você está exigindo das expressões regulares muito mais do que essa ferramenta é capaz... Que tal usar regex só pra eliminar os casos "óbvios" (i.e. aceite falsos positivos, só não deixe ter falsos negativos) em seguida fazendo uma validação mais rigorosa, usando as funções de calendário da sua plataforma?

Comment: Se possível, acompanhe [está minha solução tardia](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66954/2998), que valida meses com 30 e 31 dias, inclusive o dia 29 de fevereiro para anos bissexto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta isso

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|2020)
```

Sendo

```
Dias
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])

Mes
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])

Ano
(199[0-9]|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|2020)
```

Único problema é que não valida fevereiro (30.02.2000) por exemplo é válido.

Tem como validar as datas com essa exp, mas ai não tem limitação de ano:

```
(?:(?:(?:[01][1-9]|2[1-8])(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:29|30)(?:0[13-9]|1[0-2])|31(?:0[13578]|1[02]))[1-9]\d{3}|2902(?:[1-9]\d(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:[2468][048]|[13579][26])00))
```

Comment: Postei [está solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66954/2998) tratando esse único problema citado por você em sua resposta, por não tratar fevereiro.

Answer (score 4):

Embora @AdirKuhn já tenha fornecido uma solução aceitável ao AP. Após ter visto está fui a procura de algo mais poderoso, que pudesse ao menos validar meses com 30 e com 31 dias, pois sabia que isso era possível, apesar de saber que era trabalhoso.

Então encontrei [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26972181/2290538), que foi além das minhas expectativas, pois valida até datas para anos bissextos (no caso o dia 29 do mês de Fevereiro).

Então após algumas adaptações a língua Portuguesa (removi a opção de `01/Feb/2015`, só aceitando meses em números: `01/02/2015`), compartilho essa poderosa expressão regular para validar datas:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2)\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

O fluxograma da expressão para melhor entendimento:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Exemplo online na ferramenta utilizada para Debug e geração do fluxograma da Expressão Regular (Debuggex)](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VJX3o6R3E9uG9HNg)

Comment: +1 Achei interessante o fluxo.

Answer (score 0):

verifica se data está no formato americano aaaa-mm-dd ou no formato brasileiro dd/mm/aaaa, depois valida como dia de 01 a 31, mês 01 a 12 e ano de 1900 a 2999

/^((19[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9])-(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-2]{1,2})-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]{1,2}))|
((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]{1,2})/(0[1-9]|[1-9]|1[0-2]{1,2})/(19[0-9][0-9]|2[0-9][0-9][0-9]))$/g